# How to pass class component as a functional prop in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to send component as a prop using lambda function and TSLint throws exception.

A component can be sent as a prop like this:

```
<Test
  id={'XYZ-1809'}
  condn1={<Condn1Component />}
  condn2={<Condn2Component />}
/>
```

But when trying to send it as a functional prop, throws an error as: `Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact (jsx-no-lambda)tslint(1)`

```
<Test
  id={'XYZ-1809'}
  condn1={() => <Condn1Component />}
  condn2={() => <Condn2Component />}
/>
```

`Condn1Component` and `Condn2Component` can be a functional or class component that is unsure.

What's the best possible way to get rid of JSX-Lambda issue?

Comment: @keikai, post ur answer. I'll accept if you are seeing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to do this like below:**

```
const Condn1Component = () => {
   return (<h1>I am condition1</h1>);
} 

const Condn2Component = () => {
   return (<h1>I am condition2</h1>);
} 

const condn1ComponentHandler = () => {
  return <Condn1Component />
}

const condn2ComponentHandler = () => {
  return <Condn2Component />
}

<Test
  id={'XYZ-1809'}
  condn1={condn1ComponentHandler}
  condn2={condn2ComponentHandler}
/>
```

**And accepted as:**

```
this.props.condn1();
this.props.condn2();
```